# IndexError: string index out of range when updating a game map from text file

Tags: python-3.x

I looked at the other suggestions but none have seemed to make sense to me.

I try to make a map for my text based game and i want to display it after saving it to a text file but after about 6 y-axis coordinates it threw an error and i can't find out why. I want it to display the map from a text file. I have done lots of trial and error, some debugging, but i can't find the root of the issue.
The error was `if colonymap[x][y] == "Town Hall":`

```
elif mainInput == "colonymap":
    for y in range(maxx):
        for x in range(maxy):
            if colonymap[x][y] == "Town Hall":
                if y==locy and x==locx:
                    print ("S",end=" ")
                else:
                    print ("s",end=" ")
```

Comment: Is ```colonymap``` numpy array? If not, what type is it?

Comment: sorry for not responding. pc was dead. I don't know what it is i found it on google. ill put what the code for it is ```colonymap = [["None" for locx in range(maxx)] for locy in range(maxy)]```

Comment: This code only outputs ```None```. Are you sure the code is correct?

Comment: I just tested it. for me it outputs my game map when i run it without coming from a save file. but when i run it from a save file it throws the error.